# Angular 6 router navigation not loading external js files

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Component X is the "root", when the angular 6 web app starts you are automatically redirected to Component X. At this stage the external libraries are correctly loaded ex: Video Player and plays video fine.

However, when I click on an element of Component X and navigate to Component Y and again back to component X, I tried to play the video but ended up with some of suppporting js files were not loaded.

Tried adding `<base href="/">` in index.html and used `useHash: true` but nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0):

**This is standard behavior of a Single Page Application. SPAs will only load scripts on the initial start.**

You could do like here if needed: [Load External JS Files Dynamically](https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-load-external-javascript-file-dynamically-3d14dde815cb).

*I can not really say if this is a good or bad way, but it would work for your case*

Comment: Yeah, i have tried this approach to load dynamically. I can see those scripts have been added to the DOM but when function call goes to those scripts they are throwing "not a function" error.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to add those .js files to the angular.json definition

```
 "projects": {
    "projectname": {
      ...
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
            "scripts": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/.../your.js"
              }
            ],
          },
      }
    },
```

So they will be included in your bundle.